# Different exit/enter animations

Tags: android, animation

I want to define two window animation styles for different activities.

This is what I have so far:

**Manifest:**

```
<application
    ...>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/A" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/B" />
</application>
```

**Styles.xml:**

```
<style name="A" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomActivityAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/bottom_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/scale_out</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/scale_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/bottom_out</item>
</style>


<style name="B" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomDialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/dialog_in</item>
   <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/dialog_out</item>
</style>
```

**What I want to achieve is:**

Transitions between activities with style `A` should use the animations defined in `CustomActivityAnimation`.

Activities with style `B` are styled as a dialog and should have other transition animations defined in `CustomDialogAnimation`.

**My problem:**

The `android:windowExitAnimation` from style `CustomDialogAnimation` is never used when I close an activity from style `B`. Instead the `android:activityCloseExitAnimation` from style `CustomActivityAnimation` is played.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you demonstrate the behaviour using a gif/video? It's unclear what you currently have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I edited my post. It's hard to upload a video. If it's still unclear i'll see what i can do.

Comment: Try adding animation in style B as defined in style A), as you are using these in activity though you have given them a dialog theme.

Comment: @Nainal Tried it, didn't work.

Comment: you can give runtime instead of defining in Styles.xml!

Comment: @GaurangGoda You mean `overridePendingTransition`? I tried it, didn't work...

Comment: I have posted my answer please go through it if your problem is not solved just comment on it.

Answer (score 2):

For your purpose you can give it at runtime time as below:

we’ll need four animations in total, and we’ll be defining them through XML. Of the four animations, there are really two groups. The first is to move a view from its current position to a position out of view, and the second is to bring a view in from out of view.

Defining animation XML Files :

> slide_to_left.xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

> slide_to_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

> slide_from_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="300"/>
```

> slide_from_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
               android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

> Just as easy is animating the transition between Activities. The
>   Activity class provides us with a method called
>   overridePendingTransition that we can use to set the animation of the
>   exiting and entering Activities, like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left);
```

Using the animations we defined earlier, we can have the new Activity slide in from the right of the view, and the current Activity slides out of view to the left.

> Similarly, when the new Activity is finished, we can perform the
>   reverse animation to have the finished Activity slide out of view to
>   the right, and the previous Activity slide back into view from the
>   left:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_left, R.anim.slide_to_right);
```

> Handling on back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_left, R.anim.slide_to_right);
}
```

[credit](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/left-and-right-slide-animations-on-android-activity-or-view)

Comment: I don't want to add that code in each of my activities. Thats why i defined it in `styles.xml`

Comment: you have both activities and you are dialog theme for second activity, is there any specific reason for using dialog theme?, why don't you define enter and exit in single code form style?

Comment: Not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the parent of the dialog animation
`<style name="CustomDialogAnimation" parent="@style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog"`